# Growth chart using ggplot with dataset in the long format

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I would like to produce a growth chart using `ggplot`; however, I would like the percentile on the y-axis.

[image: GROWTH CHART]

I have this dataset and in simple terms, the goal is to "transpose" the axis.

CODE

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(ds, aes(x=quest, y = value, color = percentile, group = percentile)) +
  stat_summary(geom="line", fun = mean)

ds <-structure(list(quest = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                        4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                                        12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
                                        18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("2", 
                                                                                                 "4", "6", "8", "9", "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", 
                                                                                                 "24", "27", "30", "33", "36", "42", "48", "54", "60", "72"), class = "factor"), 
                    name = c("Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                             "Communication"), percentile = c("10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", 
                                                              "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", 
                                                              "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", 
                                                              "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", 
                                                              "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%", 
                                                              "10%", "90%", "10%", "90%"), value = c(20, 60, 35, 60, 35, 
                                                                                                     60, 35, 60, 25, 60, 20, 60, 25, 60, 20, 60, 15, 60, 10, 55, 
                                                                                                     5, 60, 10, 60, 10, 60, 18.5, 60, 25, 60, 25, 60, 25, 60, 
                                                                                                     35, 60, 35, 60, 40, 60, 35, 60, 35, 60)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                         "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -44L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                           quest = structure(1:22, .Label = c("2", "4", "6", "8", "9", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "24", "27", "30", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "33", "36", "42", "48", "54", "60", "72"), class = "factor"), 
                                                                                                                                                           name = c("Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", "Communication", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Communication", "Communication", "Communication"), .rows = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                      1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 
                                                                                                                                                                      19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25:26, 27:28, 29:30, 31:32, 33:34, 
                                                                                                                                                                      35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 41:42, 43:44), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: You should likely convert `percentile` to a number as opposed to a string. Also, you explicitly set `y=value`, does that mean you want to include a second data on the same y-axis? Perhaps `+ geom_line(aes(y=percentile))` (once converted to a number).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, when I use `ds <- ds %>% mutate(percentile = str_match_all(percentile,"[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric)

ggplot(ds, aes(x=quest, color = percentile, group = percentile)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=percentile))` it also won´t work.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted your question, sorry about the distraction.

Comment: No problems, thank you for trying to help me with that!!! =D

Comment: @Luis Were you able to figure this out? If not, could you describe further what you mean about having percentile on the y-axis? In your hand-drawing, what are the values used for the points in your line? Could you explain further what you need?